# How to bring Media Element Transport Controls in front of Media element?

Tags: mediaelement, uwp-xaml

I have a Media element that I was trying to add buttons to by using the transport controls. The Media element's source is a live stream from a camera. I don't need any of the controls for playback.

I followed [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls) for adding a custom media element and it works, but the video covers up the button. When the video is not playing I can see the controls for what I assume is the state for if a video was streaming.

Here is my xaml code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="RemoteUserUnity.MainPage"
    IsTabStop="false"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:RemoteUserUnity"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="White">




    <SwapChainPanel x:Name="DXSwapChainPanel" CompositeMode="MinBlend"  >
        <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
            <MediaElement x:Name="RemoteVideo" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" RealTimePlayback="True" AudioCategory="Communications" Stretch="UniformToFill"  Unloaded="MediaUnloaded" >
                <MediaElement.TransportControls>
                    <local:CustomMediaTransportControls x:Name="customMTC" 
                                                        Background="White"
                                                        Foreground="Blue"
                                                        Visibility="Visible"
                 IsFastForwardButtonVisible="False"
                 IsFastForwardEnabled="False"
                 IsFastRewindButtonVisible="False"
                 IsFastRewindEnabled="False"
                 IsPlaybackRateButtonVisible="False"
                 IsPlaybackRateEnabled="False"
                 IsSeekBarVisible="False"
                 IsSeekEnabled="False"
                 IsStopButtonVisible="True"
                 IsFullWindowButtonVisible="False"
                 IsFullWindowEnabled="False"
                 Circle="customMTC_Circle"
                 Arrow="customMTC_Arrow"
                 Clear="customMTC_Clear"
                 IsVolumeEnabled="False" 
                 IsZoomButtonVisible="False" 
                 IsZoomEnabled="False" 
                 IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="False" 
                 IsCompact="True" UseSystemFocusVisuals="True" />

                </MediaElement.TransportControls>
            </MediaElement>

        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="ExtendedSplashGrid" Background="White">
                <Image x:Name="ExtendedSplashImage" Source="Assets/SplashScreen.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </SwapChainPanel>



</Page>
```

How can I the controls to the foreground?

Comment: Whether the controls should be visible is defined by the style of  `MediaTransportControls`. Please find how you set the  visible property in the style or please upload the style which may in `generic.xaml` to let us  help check.

Comment: I copied the generic.xaml from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/XamlCustomMediaTransportControls/cs/Themes/generic.xaml). The controls show up in that sample so I thought it would work and when I resize the window I can actually see the control bar before the video expands to fill the window.

Comment: @Sunteen-MSFT [Here's](https://i.imgur.com/LzfgXQ7.png) what I mean. The video will then expand to cover up the buttons, but I'm still able to click on them.